# react i18n outside component

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I want to translate every promp in the Questions arrays.

I am new to this but I couldn't find a usefull solution to this online. Best I could find is that code below:

When I run like this it doesn't render at the beginning

```
import i18n from "i18next";

const aFunction = (pr) => {
  return i18n.t(pr);
};

export const Questions = [
  {
    promp: aFunction("translation1"),
    type: "A",
    type2: "AC",
  },
{
    promp: aFunction("translation2"),
    type: "A",
    type2: "AB",
  },
]
```

Comment: https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/issues/1236#issuecomment-762039023

Comment: I've saw this but I can't adapt this to my code because there is a lot of questions in the Question array

Comment: What is not working with the solution you provided?

Comment: Question.promp =   i18n.t('key1'); should  I define this for every question?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. It was a really long progress with a simple answer.

Instead of translating in an array I used this:

`<h1 className="q1">{i18n.t(Questions[cQuestion].promp)}</h1>`

and with this I can easily do this:

````
{
    promp: "translation inside the json file",
    type: "A",
    type2: "AC",
  },```
````